# python function strange behavior with arguments

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

In the following code should the output not be 6 6 7 6 but the actual output is very different as mentioned below

```
i=5
def fs(args=i):
 print args
 print i

i=6
fs()
fs(7)

Actual Output is 5 6 7 6
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code `args=i` runs when the function is *defined*, not when the function is *called*.

When you defined the function the value of `i` was 5. This means that the default value of `args` will always be 5, even if you later change the value of `i` to 6.